# Disable/enable of ion-input using angular reactive forms

Tags: ionic2

I have an Ionic app where I am trying to disable the ion-input using reactive forms some thing like this.

```
Disable(){
  this.name.disable();
  this.name.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

And when I try to enable the input element it's not working

```
 Enable(){
   this.name.enable();
   this.name.updateValueAndValidatity();
 }
```

The html code looks like this:

```
  <ion-item>
     <ion-input type="text" [formControl]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="Disable()">Disable</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="Enable()">Enable</button>
```

The above code works fine with html5 input element but not with Ionic elements. Is there something I am missing? I have made a demo example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nl1hi3?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Answer (score 1):

I have written a directive which subscribes the form control Status Changes and disables the elements using element reference. I don't whether this is correct approach but rather than writing `disabled` attribute in my html for every element I think this is good.

Because if Ionic team fixes the bug I can just delete the directive without modifying the html code. This is the link where I have the directive implemented: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bxfjzs?file=directives%2Fdisable-control.directive.ts

I need this directive for ion-input, ion-textarea and ion-radio elements. For other elements Ionic is handling the enable/disable property correctly.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. It's better indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-input type="text" [formControl]="name" [Disabled]="nameDisabled"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="Disable()">Disable</button>
  <button ion-button (click)="Enable()">Enable</button>

Disable(){
  this.nameDisabled =true;
  this.name.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. .i did that but Without adding disabled attribute is there any approach to achieve...is this a bug in ionic or is that intended to work in similar way

Comment: If you made it work can you please share your experience with us? Post it as an answer it'll be a big help. Thank you

Comment: @abhilashreddy I think this is the only way to achieve your goal with `ion-input`